# Derive ngIf value from component input

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

When I want to remove a component from the tree if some input is missing, I need to specify it twice in component declaration like this:

```html
   <app-block-with-some-data *ngIf="dataForBlock" [data]="dataForBlock">
   </app-block-with-some-data>
```

I'd like to remove the duplication while keeping the same behavior.

How do I achieve this?

Here's [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wpk5mg) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is impossible because **ngIf** is a directive, **app-block-with-some-data** is a component.

FYI: But you can use next code to use friendly-naming if you don't want to use the same names of your value.

```
<app-block-with-some-data
    *ngIf="dataForBlock; let data"
    [data]="data"
></app-block-with-some-data>
```

Comment: Yes, I guess that's the most I can do about it. Will accept this answer until something happens and it actually becomes possible.

Answer (score 1):

Well, infact you can use your data input property to bind to an ngif inside your app-block-with-some-data component's template.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'data-component',
  templateUrl: './data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data.component.css']
})
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {
Input() data: string;
```

template of the component:

```
<div *ngIf = "data">
...
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
The case related with this question is actually not against DRY. The repeat here is necessary for the components. Some things need to be clear. If a component is rendered/unrendered depending on a condition, people in your team would intuitively assume it is done with ngIf inside the template. If it is not where it's supposed to be then it's actually a tradeoff for code-readability unless it is a specific component that everybody else knows that it handles ngIf's job (rendering logic) by the provided data.

Comment: Yes, and it's described in the StackBlitz demo. The component element itself stays in the tree, and that's what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Sorry, I missed it in the stackblitz demo then and I think there is one more point to note that Im editing my answer with.

Comment: Read your update, I guess you're right, and principle of least astonishment is applicable in this situation. In the end, at some point ngIf condition may change from a simple truthy value check I have now to a complex statement or a function call and it's better to have the main logic stay the same and just change the incoming condition instead of fixing it in multiple places.